# How to use image which is in .jar file?

Tags: java, image, jframe

my "program" showing image but only when is in the same folder with the.jpg file. I want to have my image in .jar file how can i do this?
my code

```
 image = new ImageIcon("pobrane.jpg").getImage();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting images from a .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489773/getting-images-from-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pobrane.jpg")).getImage();
```