# Images disappear when exporting to a runnable jar file

Tags: java, image

I am trying to create a basic pac man clone but whenever I export my project as a runnable jar file the images (pac man and ghosts) disappear.

Here is the code I use to load the images (one example given) if you need anything else feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance!

```
Image pacmanImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img/pacman.jpg");
```

Comment: Where are your images located once you have exported the jar ?

Comment: Once I open the jar (in winrar) the img folder is there (together with thie sounds and such) and in that the images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting images from a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489773/getting-images-from-a-jar-file)

Comment: Oh thanks, I will check that out than